# Ajax Front-end Path in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I try to do plugin to Wordpress with AJAX.

In main file (plugin.php) I add ajax.js

> function add_ajax() {
>
> ```
> wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/ajax.js', __FILE__ ));
> wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax.js' );
> wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
> ```
>
> }
>
> add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax' );

My ajax script look like:

```
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
     var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
     ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
     }
     }
     var kid = document.getElementById('kid').value;
     var queryString = "?kid=" + kid;
     ajaxRequest.open("GET", "users.php" + queryString, true);
     ajaxRequest.send(null);
     }
```

In user.php i have callback

```
    $kid = $_GET['kid'];
      if(!empty($kid)) {

        $dropdown = "";

       for($i=1;$i<=$kid;$i++){
       $dropdown .= "<div><label><span>User #".$i."</span><input type=text></label></div>";
       }


      echo $dropdown;
}
```

I have Error 404. WP can't find file user.php. How can i fix the path to User.php? I thnik, that /wp-content/plugins/mine/uses.php is incorrect.

Thanks for help me

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typographical error:

Change this:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "users.php" + queryString, true);
```

To this:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "user.php" + queryString, true);
```